# How can import error be solved when importing ezsheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets

Trying to get connected with ezsheets while working through Automate the Boring Stuff with Python. I get stuck at the 'import ezsheets' step.

I've done the `pip install --user ezsheets` step, as well as downloading the credentials file from google (all steps can be found [here](https://ezsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

I've renamed the credentials file as credentials-sheets.json, and placed it in the correct directory.

The documentation says that this should give one of those Google popups - but I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'credentials' from 'google.auth' (/home/dominic/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/__init__.py)
```

Comment: What version of Python are you running on?  I seem to recall running into a similar issue, and part of the problem is Automate the Boring Stuff is slightly out of date for some of these packages now (I think it was written for Python 3.6 or 3.7)

Comment: Also, can you show the lines of code where you're doing the import?  This could be a typo or case issue, (such as 'credentials' vs "Credentials").  Is it the `quickstart.py` code that's throwing this error?

Comment: @nigh_anxiety, I'm using Python 3.9.2

The line of code for the import is just "import ezsheets". The file is called "credentials-sheets.json". It's in my main folder "/home/dominic", as is "test.py" - the script that contains just the line "import ezsheets".

I'm not sure on quickstart.py - could you provide some more info on this? I don't recognise the name. Thanks!

Comment: Scroll down the ezsheets documentation page and there is a link to the Google Sheets Python Quickstart guide (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python/), follow the directions there, but you might need to change credentials.json in their to credentials-sheets.json, or vice versa

Comment: @nigh_anxiety - thanks for your help my issue is resolved :) for anyone coming across this later - using the quickstart page, I also installed the next line of code `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib` and then ran `import ezsheets` and it was all sorted